# Bison: Fixed shift/reduce errors, no clue how

Tags: bison, yacc, shift-reduce-conflict

So I was having the dreaded shift/reduce errors with my grammar. Here's a minimal test case:

```
%token PLUS MINUS TIMES DIVIDE NUMBER
%token EQUAL NEQUAL GREATER LESS NOT

%left   EQUAL   NEQUAL
%left   GREATER LESS
%left   PLUS    MINUS
%left   TIMES   DIVIDE
%left   UMINUS  NOT

%%

exp             : exp binop exp
                | unop exp
                | NUMBER
                ;

binop           : MINUS
                | PLUS
                | TIMES
                | DIVIDE
                | EQUAL
                | NEQUAL
                | GREATER
                | LESS
                ;

unop            : MINUS %prec UMINUS
                | NOT
                ;

%%
```

However, through experimentation I somehow managed to make the problem go away:

```
%token PLUS MINUS TIMES DIVIDE NUMBER
%token EQUAL NEQUAL GREATER LESS NOT

%left   EQUAL   NEQUAL
%left   GREATER LESS
%left   PLUS    MINUS
%left   TIMES   DIVIDE
%left   UMINUS  NOT

%%

exp             : binops
                | unops
                | NUMBER
                ;

unops           : MINUS exp %prec UMINUS
                | NOT exp
                ;

binops          : exp MINUS exp
                | exp PLUS exp
                | exp TIMES exp
                | exp DIVIDE exp
                | exp EQUAL exp
                | exp NEQUAL exp
                | exp GREATER exp
                | exp LESS exp
                ;

%%
```

Can anyone explain why I was having shift/reduce errors in the first place and why this worked? Is this even a proper solution? If not, what is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first grammar, the precedence declarations do absolutely nothing. Precedence only applies to the alternatives containing the *terminal* with the precedence; in your first grammar, that would be the productions for `binop` and `unop`. But the alternatives for those productions are completely unambiguous; precedence is not required to decide to reduce `PLUS` to `binop`.

In your second grammar, the precedence relationships do have an effect because the competing ambiguous alternatives (the productions for `binops` and `unops`) directly include the terminals.

In other words, precedence does not "look into" a non-terminal.